# If turtle touches square?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

If i have a randomly generated square in a turtle window(50 pixels * 50 pixels), and I have a turtle(player), is there any way to detect the turtle touching the square? Is there any certain line of code? Perhaps, something along the lines of "if turtle is on/touching color"?

Comment: A cursory search does not seem to reveal any applicable method.  The next best thing would seem to be simply checking the coordinates of the square and the turtle.

Comment: Can you please post a minimal, complete, verifiable example of the code that creates your square and turtle? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to handle this is to make your target square itself a turtle.  Then you can determine if the player turtle is *touching* the target square turtle using the turtle's `.distance()` method.

A minimalist example -- you can move the turtle using the arrow keys and if you manage to park the turtle in the square, the program quits:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()

square = Turtle('square', visible=False)
square.shapesize(50 / CURSOR_SIZE)
square.color('red', 'white')
square.penup()
square.goto(175, 287)
square.showturtle()

turtle = Turtle('turtle')
turtle.color('dark green', 'green')
turtle.penup()

def move():
    turtle.forward(10)

    if turtle.distance(square) < 15:
        screen.bye()  # program ends if turtle enters square

screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.left(45), 'Left')
screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.right(45), 'Right')
screen.onkey(move, 'Up')

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```